# Android: Forcing audio to earpiece >> setDeviceConnectionState failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Tags: java, android, audio

I am totally new in coding, in fact I am not a coder but trying to solve an issue that when a headset is connected, still i want to use the earpiece.

After couple of days of search, I came across a sample from here (http://oneyoung.im/2014/12/26/force-route-audio-stream-to-headphone/).

I downloaded and installed Android Studio and tried above class. But I am getting an error.

```
12-02 13:28:48.652 6475-6475/com.free.alahdal.stopheadset E/AudioTest: setDeviceConnectionState failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setDeviceConnectionState [int, int, class java.lang.String]
```

Following is MyActivity.java & AudioTest.java

MyActivity:

```
package com.free.alahdal.stopheadset;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AudioTest at = new AudioTest();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }


    public void offHeadset(View view) {
      at.forceRouteHeadset(false);
    }

    public void onHeadset(View view) {
      at.forceRouteHeadset(true);
    }

}
```

Below is the AudioTest

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class AudioTest {
    private final String TAG = "AudioTest";
     // Constants copied from AudioSystem
    private static final int DEVICE_IN_WIRED_HEADSET    = 0x400000;
    private static final int DEVICE_OUT_EARPIECE        = 0x1;
    private static final int DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADSET   = 0x4;
    private static final int DEVICE_STATE_UNAVAILABLE   = 0;
    private static final int DEVICE_STATE_AVAILABLE     = 1;

    /* force route function through AudioSystem */
    private void setDeviceConnectionState(final int device, final int state, final String address) {
        try {
            Class<?> audioSystem = Class.forName("android.media.AudioSystem");
            Method setDeviceConnectionState = audioSystem.getMethod(
                    "setDeviceConnectionState", int.class, int.class, String.class);

            setDeviceConnectionState.invoke(audioSystem, device, state, address);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "setDeviceConnectionState failed: " + e);
        }
    }

    public void forceRouteHeadset(boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            Log.i(TAG, "force route to Headset");
            setDeviceConnectionState(DEVICE_IN_WIRED_HEADSET, DEVICE_STATE_AVAILABLE, "");
            setDeviceConnectionState(DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADSET, DEVICE_STATE_AVAILABLE, "");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "force route to Earpirce");
            setDeviceConnectionState(DEVICE_IN_WIRED_HEADSET, DEVICE_STATE_UNAVAILABLE, "");
            setDeviceConnectionState(DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADSET, DEVICE_STATE_UNAVAILABLE, "");
            setDeviceConnectionState(DEVICE_OUT_EARPIECE, DEVICE_STATE_AVAILABLE, "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I am totally new in coding* then **do not use hack** that you do not understand ... simply this **hack** using reflection to get some class and call some method **which is not a part of Android's API** ... this class(and/or methods) may or may not exist on the device ... in your case(for given device/emulator) this class does exists but doesn't have give method ...

Comment: You mean the code is correct but doesn't work in my device?

Comment: I wouldn't call "using undocumented API" as correct code ... but yes, it may work on some(mostly older) devices ...

Comment: Any other way? To be more precise, I have an item which is similar to pressy (Klick). When I connect it, the phone thinks it is a headset and routes all audio to WIRED_HEADSET. I want the phone to ignore that and routes the audio to the earpiece.

Comment: no ... just compare method definition from [froyo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/froyo/media/java/android/media/AudioSystem.java#L284) with [marshmallow](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/media/java/android/media/AudioSystem.java#L612) ... and with your `audioSystem.getMethod` call parameters

Answer (score 3):

Here is the method you want to use for reflection.

```
/**
 * Indicate wired accessory connection state change.
 * @param device type of device connected/disconnected (AudioManager.DEVICE_OUT_xxx)
 * @param state  new connection state: 1 connected, 0 disconnected
 * @param name   device name
 * {@hide}
 */
public void setWiredDeviceConnectionState(int type, int state, String address, String name) {
    IAudioService service = getService();
    try {
        service.setWiredDeviceConnectionState(type, state, address, name,
                mApplicationContext.getOpPackageName());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Dead object in setWiredDeviceConnectionState "+e);
    }
}
```

This method is using four parameters (above kitkat versions) and three parameters till kitkat.
The method which you are using is not in the api that's why it's throwing such exception.
Don't forget to accept if it helps.